Deriving 2D Transformation Matrix From Points
Newbie hobbyist here, so be gentle.
I am working on an object recognition project where I want to compare the similarity of two 2D (i.e., only x and y axes) line segments using the Frechet distance.  I have a known line segment (SegmentK) and a possible matching segment that I an querying (SegmentQ).  Both segments are made from a series of points describing a contour.  Each segment has at least three points but could have more and SegmentK could have more or less points that SegmentQ.  SegmentQ may be the the same/similar to SegmentK but translated, scaled, and/or rotated.
My idea is to:

assume that the end points of the segments (SegmentK.startpoint, SegmentK.endpoint, SegmentQ.startpoint, SegmentQ.endpoint) match each other;
figure out what transformation matrix would render a match between at least the end points;
apply that transformation matrix to all the other points in SegmentQ; and
figure out the Frechet distance between the two segments.

Now my questions:

Can this be done using only two points or do I need three or more points?

Regardless of whether it is two or three points or more, how do I derive the transformation matrix that addresses translation, scale and rotation?


I see a lot of stuff on deriving the transformation matrix between two points but it is not clear to me whether that matrix includes rotation (I think not).  If it was just one aspect at a time, I could derive the matrix but I do not know how to do it when it is all three issues.  I know of Gaus-Jordan elimination and Cramer's Rule but my linear algebra knowledge is VERY limited.
To address complications, I also know that the starting and end point matches may be reversed but, for the purposes of my question, let's assume that they are correct.  Also, this is in computer graphics.  So the origin is top left and the Y axis increases going down.
Any help appreciated, especially any help explaining it to someone with my limited linear algebra knowledge.
Thanks
